# Stop JqueryUI Datepicker Months Navigation After A particular Year Ends

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have used a JqueryUI datepicker, I have to add a list of holidays for a particular year.

Is there any way to disable datepicker's month navigation After a particuler Year Ends?

eg. If I am adding Holidays list for year 2014, then I want to disable Datepicker's Prev Month Navigation (Prev Button) When January 2014 Month is Selected. And if December 2014 Month is selected, then I want to disable Next Month Navigation button(Next Button). Further I do Not want to use ChangeYear/ChangeMonth options on datepicker.

My Code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtHolidayDate").datepicker(
         {
             dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
         });
});
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/8r2VZ/) to restrict the date range to the year entered by the user. Check it out !

HTML:

```
<h3>Currently the dates are restricted to year 2014</h3>
Enter Year to restrict date range to:
<input type="text" id="year" size="30" value="2014"/>
<input type="button" id="change_year" value="Change Year">
<br>
Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var year_val = 2014;
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        minDate: new Date(year_val, 1 - 1, 1),
        maxDate: new Date(year_val, 11, 31)
    });

    $('#change_year').click(function(){
        if($('#year').val() != "")
        {
            year_val = $('#year').val();
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(year_val, 1 - 1, 1) );
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", new Date(year_val, 11, 31) );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @Rahul. It worked fine. I have also tried the same with 
onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {} Event of Datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `yearRange` option in `datepicker`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/203/

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtHolidayDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        yearRange:'2014:2014',
    });
});
```

Moreover, you can also set this option whenever you need using:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ yearRange: "2002:2012" });
```